# Shortcode in shortcode: How to append variable?

Tags: shortcode

In below example, I wrapped `[contact-form-7 id="33"]` inside another shortcode `[myform]`. So, when posting, just use `[myform]` istead:

```
function wrapthecode() {
    return do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="33"]');
}
add_shortcode( 'myform', 'wrapthecode' );
```

But how to append variable ID on the new shortcode?

Means `[myform id="33"]` is `[contact-form-7 id="33"]` and `[myform id="34"]` is `[contact-form-7 id="34"]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to get the attributes of the shortcode, which is quite simple and  documented in the [`add_shortcode()` examples](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Examples):

```
function wrapthecode( $attr ) {
    if( empty( $attr['id'] ) )
        return 'No ID given.';

    return do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="' . $attr['id'] . '"]');
}
add_shortcode( 'myform', 'wrapthecode' );
```